# Data with multicollinearity and p >> n

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, high-dimensional

This is a csv file, the file is titled "res_final". The first line contains the names of the variables:

```
"";"age";"sex";"A";"B";"es";"C";"7";"8";"9";"10";"11";"12";"13";"14";"15";"16";"17";"18";"19";"20";"21";"22";"23";"24";"25";"26";"27";"28";"29";"30";"31";"32";"33";"34";"35";"36";"37";"38";"39";"40";"41";"42";"43";"44";"45";"46";"47";"48";"49";"50";"51";"52";"53";"54"
"1";64;"F";61;3;"Primaria";1;0,619666666666667;0,372333333333333;0,438333333333333;0,504;0,2795;0,3415;0,239;0,274;0,2175;0,2695;0,3005;0,191;0,433;0,393;0,461;0,575;4,2965;4,08;4,1935;5,7675;4,5515;3,7005;2,889;5,16;4,9395;4,0305;2,585;6,196;3,6235;3,9365;1,664;4,0405;6,6985;4,197;4,5055;10,9865;7,1465;4,8465;3,6735;10,415;6,453;4,343;4,827;10,732;5,783;5,569;3,186;8,137
"2";62;"M";59;3;"Pre-Univer";17;0,559;0,390333333333333;0,301333333333333;0,283333333333333;0,361;0,3275;0,256;0,2615;0,362;0,285;0,239;0,186;0,22;0,036;0,272;0,424;6,8745;7,599;4,479;4,507;6,8575;6,6805;4,8915;4,698;7,5385;6,9745;2,862;1,7525;8,9965;6,318;2,5775;1,277;28,334;9,9865;2,331;2,6095;13,066;6,6015;2,365;1,834;21,793;11,614;2,042;2,188;13,476;7,301;2,161;1,354
"3";64;"F";62;2;"Universita";24;0,368666666666667;0,395333333333333;0,330666666666667;0,150666666666667;0,2655;0,24;0,267;0,2145;0,448;0,341;0,4485;0,365;0,664;0,377;0,541;0,288;8,813;7,2515;5,6085;6,781;9,984;8,3535;7,0155;7,8325;8,0785;3,6035;2,358;3,602;7,6525;3,335;0,9885;3,5755;17,057;7,362;1,875;8,8795;10,8625;5,2345;1,813;6,09;15,827;4,304;1,664;6,315;16,943;4,073;1,367;6,312
"4";58;"M";56;2;"Secundaria";22;0,510666666666667;0,610333333333333;0,768666666666667;0,366;0,3375;0,065;0,407;0,2505;0,347;0,3575;0,532;0,3415;0,441;0,478;0,669;0,461;4,5175;3,838;6,3665;12,9915;4,7455;4,0085;6,089;12,06;3,514;1,5465;5,166;17,6615;3,256;1,3635;4,5015;14,5405;7,5385;2,6535;8,9565;19,803;6,193;4,3655;10,8955;26,7145;6,779;6,779;9,951;39,961;6,842;6,842;9,378;44,552
"5";66;"F";65;1;"Secundaria";16;0,367333333333333;0,373;0,31;0,299;0,4995;0,389;0,321;0,2675;0,4915;0,174;0,1725;0,1875;0,195;0,206;0,223;0,475;3,7125;4,5425;3,49;3,3705;3,3686;4,0871;3,4786;2,9996;6,424;8,5005;2,907;2,698;4,6;7,682;2,1885;2,7345;7,7315;8,018;5,0675;3,5835;5,8295;6,867;4,4045;3,2415;10,939;10,514;2,813;3,947;12,598;16,39;3,992;6,281
"6";61;"F";58;3;"Primaria";1;0,61;0,397;0,503;0,471333333333333;0,22;0,212;0,2195;0,3215;0,266;0,198;0,239;0,2575;0,543;0,503;0,397;0,329;5,233;4,8045;4,9195;4,9185;5,3335;4,5755;4,503;4,8175;3,851;2,557;3,558;3,8165;3,887;2,469;4,2695;4,0825;4,7925;3,158;6,055;5,2755;5,922;3,6925;7,825;6,969;5,496;3,733;6,992;6,238;5,639;3,636;6,206;6,221
"7";77;"F";76;1;"Secundaria";16;0,752;0,449666666666667;0,499;0,257333333333333;0,4685;0,3275;0,157;0,277;0,386;0,356;0,219;0,299;0,753;0,236;0,458;0,546;34,0465;13,792;13,268;13,7235;32,81;11,2145;10,752;11,0735;49,4985;3,4085;1,245;2,205;28,859;2,454;1,129;1,777;94,978;5,449;1,59;4,2965;76,2635;4,848;1,942;3,859;131,431;4,098;1,808;4,817;49,754;2,966;1,81;3,099
"8";55;"M";54;1;"Universita";18;0,448;0,373333333333333;0,400333333333333;0,567666666666667;0,239;0,414;0,3585;0,3445;0,3295;0,3135;0,3345;0,2525;0,556;0,459;0,253;0,285;3,724;4,092;4,892;4,666;2,32;2,824;3,7835;3,6895;2,783;2,2735;6,075;5,0835;3,6445;3,697;6,2225;6,1055;3,7505;2,8265;10,455;7,2195;4,9235;2,9505;9,1775;8,186;3,676;2,629;9,684;8,429;5,514;3,871;11,319;12,083
"9";50;"F";49;1;"Universita";21;0,719333333333333;0,468333333333333;0,515666666666667;0,378;0,374;0,162;0,3165;0,416;0,2135;0,4515;0,165;0,3885;0,276;0,435;0,23;0,429;5,5635;4,908;3,4605;3,352;5,2535;6,051;3,722;3,804;5,603;4,6655;3,367;2,3585;4,3635;3,5235;2,3305;1,644;11,5935;8,7815;4,947;3,585;19,3465;9,6655;7,785;5,002;9,117;6,121;4,256;2,698;24,375;7,474;3,282;3,255
"10";63;"F";60;3;"Primaria";23;0,600666666666667;0,422333333333333;0,524666666666667;0,552;0,6015;0,5025;0,2895;0,336;0,2995;0,3585;0,346;0,157;0,037;0,047;0,193;0,251;9,3455;6,9255;5,9665;5,838;7,8645;5,876;5,0535;4,926;6,0925;3,689;1,72;1,2505;10,2615;5,0425;2,9125;1,5255;23,1895;8,729;3,285;3,093;21,451;8,0185;3,721;2,9305;27,504;9,441;3,505;2,911;40,576;12,847;4,463;3,914
"11";66;"F";63;3;"Primaria";16;0,607666666666667;0,446666666666667;0,742;0,578;0,1805;0,396;0,1775;0,2325;0,3575;0,365;0,4345;0,454;0,179;0,297;0,558;0,455;5,741;4,374;4,172;6,063;7,645;5,7045;5,665;7,3715;14,7885;3,2215;2,3625;5,9025;12,8;3,561;2,691;6,2665;13,601;2,9395;4,9215;11,1295;13,472;2,778;3,106;10,4335;17,648;3,689;6,002;17,587;16,274;3,906;6,742;18,355
"12";71;"M";70;1;"Primaria";22;0,472;0,380333333333333;0,388333333333333;0,261;0,4545;0,246;0,155;0,22;0,56;0,51;0,203;0,1925;0,463;0,584;0,554;0,618;7,0815;4,304;6,983;5,515;8,4115;4,937;7,7105;7,088;5,9155;1,4155;6,9925;5,3235;5,363;1,1745;7,329;4,8485;17,606;4,29;10,5045;12,012;10,78;2,196;14,029;7,138;23,124;4,09;8,262;11,558;14,332;2,144;6,934;6,652
"13";68;"F";66;2;"Universita";25;0,641666666666667;0,495333333333333;0,444666666666667;0,463333333333333;0,1915;0,1735;0,0785;0,352;0,431;0,2415;0,3275;0,394;0,358;0,345;0,271;0,646;11,0155;6,7615;5,4215;5,8135;11,865;6,652;5,6665;6,251;10,815;4,0825;1,539;2,114;12,751;3,1025;1,8765;2,0945;43,809;5,182;2,1395;4,9295;61,225;6,2875;6,2485;8,893;24,057;4,922;1,952;3,467;16,778;4,365;2,132;3,354
"14";72;"F";70;2;"Primaria";22;0,551666666666667;0,495666666666667;0,413;0,514;0,211;0,229;0,2935;0,2415;0,355;0,435;0,2795;0,401;0,167;0,657;0,168;0,297;3,268;5,2245;3,5075;2,8135;3,2825;5,48;3,0155;2,458;3,822;8,6565;2,905;2,21;3,294;6,8305;3,608;1,708;5,8475;6,364;3,4335;2,899;6,2595;6,165;3,782;2,7365;4,568;7,244;2,963;2,572;5,22;6,687;3,447;2,887
"15";88;"F";87;1;"Universita";16;0,38;0,353;0,683666666666667;0,194666666666667;0,3535;0,1645;0,379;0,408;0,4015;0,32;0,4515;0,353;0,344;0,214;0,794;0,041;6,7295;4,9075;6,1145;7,598;5,5425;4,2925;5,7215;6,831;8,762;2,689;3,4;8,083;6,442;4,2305;4,503;4,845;7,904;2,299;3,7995;8,2845;7,181;3,171;8,0965;7,845;13,42;2,907;4,609;21,841;11,005;2,785;4,042;11,31
"16";70;"F";67;3;"Secundaria";23;0,735;0,364;0,308666666666667;0,368333333333333;0,327;0,277;0,1305;0,1905;0,4515;0,3305;0,29;0,3485;0,277;0,08;0,25;0,353;5,5175;3,7;5,2545;4,0285;6,4665;3,9395;5,1495;4,685;4,86;4,3485;4,838;2,511;8,6725;5,621;5,903;3,55;4,3045;3,9285;5,115;3,4945;10,559;3,9935;5,9335;3,4415;19,035;4,937;3,963;2,911;24,026;6,389;4,512;3,733
"17";47;"M";46;1;"Pre-Univer";22;0,49;0,279;0,357666666666667;0,309333333333333;0,3465;0,1445;0,288;0,33;0,251;0,2795;0,1945;0,212;0,21;0,209;0,344;0,374;9,1935;6,851;7,6565;6,7305;10,825;7,157;9,0135;7,46;14,092;2,6205;4,2545;2,533;9,542;3,08;3,5215;2,5215;16,31;5,281;7,504;6,0495;10,524;4,3505;6,032;4,171;31,432;4,942;4,7;3,497;19,212;5,399;4,11;3,351
"18";69;"F";68;1;"Secundaria";22;0,564;0,415666666666667;0,238666666666667;0,210333333333333;0,119;0,1835;0,2015;0,176;0,5;0,259;0,2925;0,2665;0,471;0,297;0,237;0,478;7,9225;8,288;7,471;6,2025;7,215;6,7965;6,6015;5,2875;7,239;5,444;1,622;1,63;5,427;5,5585;1,45;1,355;11,6585;5,2515;2,079;2,039;16,0215;6,1275;3,1225;3,0275;8,448;6,193;1,871;1,97;9,179;6,612;1,992;1,898
"19";57;"F";56;1;"Pre-Univer";20;0,212666666666667;0,232;0,297333333333333;0,251;0,27;0,3515;0,0855;0,139;0,369;0,2035;0,256;0,2385;0,301;0,12;0,436;0,399;3,846;3,989;6,1715;5,9345;3,4555;3,584;5,6625;5,7675;2,884;1,828;8,9295;6,6575;3,0215;1,702;6,9775;7,6955;6,5425;3,3225;10,252;10,632;6,7485;2,8135;8,7165;8,9525;4,619;1,995;6,935;6,926;4,026;1,726;6,829;7,299
"20";75;"M";73;2;"Secundaria";16;0,516;0,336333333333333;0,464333333333333;0,400333333333333;0,1775;0,3395;0,458;0,1485;0,202;0,175;0,1115;0,175;0,085;0,011;0,177;0,048;6,881;4,5205;9,502;11,7345;6,2105;4,1185;6,1795;11,255;9,419;1,8325;6,4455;27,2775;6,915;1,599;4,5135;14,8125;8,035;1,411;6,582;21,715;12,1205;1,718;5,9815;19,0735;19,514;2,145;13,237;77,801;17,078;2,269;7,91;33,005
"21";78;"F";77;1;"Primaria";23;0,400333333333333;0,141333333333333;0,346666666666667;0,264333333333333;0,1805;0,0995;0,14;0,221;0,177;0,2565;0,275;0,18;0,057;0,111;0,244;0,308;5,9965;4,478;4,7185;4,7815;6,087;4,619;4,5905;5,0185;7,3905;3,0045;2,9315;4,37;8,675;3,1125;5,014;5,2315;21,968;3,2485;3,343;13,9425;16,7225;3,9925;3,7685;9,526;17,693;4,76;4,601;8,448;22,205;4,076;4,802;5,772
"22";67;"F";65;2;"Universita";23;0,461;0,298;0,285;0,257666666666667;0,5225;0,432;0,1415;0,068;0,261;0,182;0,2635;0,2735;0,397;0,139;0,205;0,105;3,522;2,745;4,665;4,964;3,842;3,2915;6,4265;5,738;3,462;2,265;5,684;5,1595;5,055;2,544;6,138;4,916;5,166;7,5925;6,7935;6,3305;7,5115;8,1855;7,4745;7,3015;0,093;4,773;7,062;6,183;6,777;3,138;6,155;5,252
"23";48;"M";46;2;"Pre-Univer";1;0,597333333333333;0,247333333333333;0,453;0,237333333333333;0,33;0,1935;0,261;0,0895;0,2575;0,2085;0,33;0,2065;0,197;0,132;0,167;0,447;5,514;3,2075;4,692;5,124;7,527;4,318;6,091;6,0485;6,8335;2,1495;2,5525;3,3565;7,148;1,983;4,3135;3,8955;31,8085;6,013;4,275;9,551;19,9475;7,7445;2,6455;7,6965;17,739;2,95;2,413;4,35;8,512;3,109;2,285;3,21
"24";57;"F";56;1;"Secundaria";23;0,833666666666667;0,359333333333333;0,278;0,183666666666667;0,206;0,157;0,358;0,264;0,5215;0,288;0,243;0,263;0,616;0,218;0,042;0,138;5,696;4,4565;5,4825;3,946;5,5105;4,4;3,701;3,092;11,854;6,481;3,31;2,4855;11,132;7,1185;5,0345;2,935;17,2455;5,829;2,5315;2,7755;14,144;4,259;3,124;2,674;20,574;11,437;2,483;2,478;25,982;7,358;2,271;2,861
"25";48;"F";47;1;"Secundaria";22;0,799666666666667;0,397333333333333;0,515666666666667;0,389333333333333;0,5885;0,5475;0,2925;0,464;0,6895;0,2855;0,2515;0,3425;0,858;0,399;0,57;0,694;5,706;4,405;5,1565;3,746;6,8485;5,157;6,6595;5,0275;5,353;3,6065;2,7705;1,994;7,636;4,585;2,6645;1,418;15,074;7,263;2,3425;3,3045;21,296;8,437;4,5475;2,8625;16,889;7,061;3,826;3,173;24,254;10,856;4,039;2,92
"26";63;"M";62;1;"Secundaria";19;0,502666666666667;0,365333333333333;0,350333333333333;0,386333333333333;0,302;0,2795;0,1825;0,1325;0,3925;0,4015;0,1225;0,349;0,586;0,694;0,39;0,359;5,0575;4,385;9,1525;5,2865;4,415;4,0325;5,5225;4,374;4,44;4,013;10,6065;4,266;3,385;2,6215;8,148;3,568;10,828;3,8715;9,822;6,575;11,341;3,2855;8,1775;4,9965;6,221;3,646;6,477;4,297;6,331;3,635;10,111;4,714
"27";56;"F";54;2;"Pre-Univer";16;0,292333333333333;0,291333333333333;0,270333333333333;0,235333333333333;0,4095;0,238;0,1735;0,277;0,2985;0,207;0,195;0,37;0,152;0,163;0,387;0,629;3,486;4,2335;7,052;5,883;3,724;3,7635;6,773;5,408;3,615;4,1775;4,412;3,5195;3,2545;4,0345;4,5855;3,4905;4,208;5,405;8,7075;6,3275;4,7915;4,5505;5,1705;5,034;4,275;5,645;5,986;5,011;3,076;3,301;5,076;4,425
"28";68;"F";66;2;"Primaria";1;0,280666666666667;0,248666666666667;0,246666666666667;0,355666666666667;0,2395;0,3145;0,1845;0,533;0,3445;0,2615;0,3055;0,446;0,235;0,336;0,339;0,661;3,916;2,958;14,001;7,1175;4,1385;2,968;13,0745;7,2145;5,809;2,67;9,35;7,5225;5,5895;2,188;9,3185;5,852;5,894;2,6245;13,7105;9,8895;4,3885;1,723;14,9895;8,6585;4,762;2,107;11,055;7,517;3,872;1,517;12,442;6,874
"29";60;"F";59;1;"Pre-Univer";23;0,591333333333333;0,203;0,238;0,206666666666667;0,304;0,28;0,121;0,188;0,419;0,245;0,1535;0,069;0,099;0,197;0,233;0,433;5,74605;4,129;5,195;4,3835;5,0165;4,0565;4,854;4,588;8,2515;4,3915;2,295;2,933;6,9495;4,0125;3,975;3,293;12,7465;5,8345;3,535;4,9695;13,765;5,6085;8,768;5,3685;18,99;6,62;2,812;4,114;16,509;6,171;2,913;3,756
"30";56;"F";55;1;"Secundaria";1;0,85;0,575333333333333;0,633;0,525;0,807;0,8845;0,618;0,708;0,6995;0,7095;0,8195;0,68;0,627;0,603;0,415;0,151;5,7715;3,359;16,2765;12,3495;11,4045;6,4555;19,251;15,7685;6,542;1,473;15,4365;11,55;5,3965;1,4205;10,0465;13,0895;7,007;2,634;15,498;14,491;19,8935;1,6585;21,633;17,1015;9,422;2,085;18,185;16,494;21,596;2,208;19,18;16,959
"31";58;"M";57;1;"Universita";18;0,197;0,130666666666667;0,319333333333333;0,117;0,142;0,17;0,186;0,087;0,229;0,287;0,244;0,141;0,087;0,31;0,23;0,214;12,391;9,6645;21,275;24,2035;12,1755;6,121;16,5555;24,4205;4,7615;1,692;12,8225;12,362;4,934;1,6085;9,328;20,329;18,153;3,9305;29,127;77,551;7,533;2,8585;21,0785;52,651;17,51;1,984;16,138;42,674;6,654;1,694;7,032;48,298
"32";50;"F";49;1;"Pre-Univer";18;0,446666666666667;0,35;0,551;0,49;0,3645;0,392;0,135;0,304;0,3185;0,4445;0,4065;0,396;0,117;0,324;0,358;0,375;6,142;4,006;10,361;6,579;7,7725;4,642;6,803;6,4825;5,7895;2,018;3,2985;6,5475;6,367;2,279;4,2595;7,183;14,644;3,8265;9,3695;11,923;14,097;4,27;12,533;13,949;14,518;2,848;6,188;11,594;17,687;3,537;8,693;13,27
"33";57;"F";55;2;"Universita";19;0,769;0,786333333333333;0,412666666666667;0,258;0,554;0,438;0,376;0,45;0,505;0,417;0,5375;0,5025;0,455;0,597;0,246;0,556;6,928;5,181;8,098;6,0155;5,8145;4,6815;8,567;5,0355;7,776;2,476;3,881;2,2945;8,664;2,772;3,035;2,249;19,9305;5,98;4,126;2,6515;42,5865;6,5;28,5505;11,477;15,162;5,106;3,796;2,407;15,855;4,795;3,832;2,648
"34";82;"F";80;2;"Primaria";15;0,859333333333333;0,542;0,408666666666667;0,602666666666667;0,7485;0,603;0,5705;0,384;0,8285;0,363;0,085;0,516;0,718;0,575;0,317;0,461;7,0665;6,37;11,8585;7,0125;8,702;6,291;10,058;7,527;9,132;2,341;6,453;4,2315;10,299;2,916;3,906;3,823;13,9395;3,838;7,093;8,3945;20,9225;3,6335;10,9255;9,353;20,247;4,304;5,563;4,798;16,963;3,25;18,779;9,06
"35";50;"F";48;2;"Universita";24;0,377;0,147333333333333;0,388333333333333;0,227;0,333;0,34;0,2485;0,1875;0,4505;0,392;0,3055;0,282;0,087;0,41;0,445;0,418;4,932;4,9125;8,078;6,048;8,0175;15,1465;7,7525;6,135;4,845;1,893;4,254;5,228;4,5275;1,876;6,086;5,3855;6,0865;2,875;4,958;6,491;8,8625;3,104;5,673;8,0815;10,308;2,669;5,709;8;6,098;2,36;5,692;5,842
"36";64;"F";63;1;"Primaria";7;0,294666666666667;0,325;0,297666666666667;0,22;0,3125;0,3355;0,26;0,1245;0,209;0,1995;0,2025;0,393;0,219;0,191;0,232;0,179;4,562;4,805;11,1775;5,556;3,609;4,539;11,775;4,1025;13,1565;9,3545;86,493;28,0625;4,2515;5,9175;23,9725;6,3755;3,0095;5,8705;4,1995;2,437;2,5285;5,4465;4,325;2,294;2,808;4,211;4,771;2,295;5,548;6,857;41,123;10,523
"37";64;"F";62;2;"Universita";16;0,389;0,219666666666667;0,391333333333333;0,231;0,272;0,422;0,162;0,1915;0,26;0,2445;0,339;0,1795;0,253;0,229;0,198;0,069;5,397;5,0975;8,0805;5,627;4,1375;3,51;5,3975;4,2515;4,084;4,4135;4,51;2,6325;4,1265;3,422;3,9005;2,488;10,795;6,4825;5,997;4,6975;13,5505;5,3475;8,3015;4,803;7,543;6,199;15,42;7,578;7,61;4,129;7,766;3,582
"38";57;"M";56;1;"Secundaria";24;0,494333333333333;0,354;0,287;0,173333333333333;0,366;0,2975;0,1455;0,146;0,3345;0,21;0,3;0,2375;0,168;0,155;0,316;0,231;9,693;5,8285;7,292;7,034;8,394;5,0655;6,1595;6,035;11,313;2,423;3,7445;3,4025;8,972;2,495;3,052;4,0965;38,926;3,315;9,1295;8,3225;32,077;3,212;4,393;6,9445;20,152;2,748;6,02;5,675;16,017;2,939;4,349;4,181
"39";60;"F";59;1;"Secundaria";13;0,327;0,222333333333333;0,311666666666667;0,393333333333333;0,2555;0,246;0,3035;0,6645;0,158;0,227;0,33;0,618;0,448;0,532;0,598;0,787;4,3145;4,144;11,0205;6,247;5,2185;5,0435;12,006;12,2125;2,337;1,9525;17,123;15,486;1,593;0,7575;16,691;14,858;3,631;3,596;15,1;10,4535;4,582;5,2685;14,7705;14,863;1,668;1,335;17,749;6,405;2,005;1,205;10,326;8,844
"40";65;"F";64;1;"Pre-Univer";16;0,309333333333333;0,340666666666667;0,309333333333333;0,129333333333333;0,3995;0,309;0,3995;0,1685;0,2075;0,2685;0,2075;0,2415;0,268;0,373;0,268;0,214;5,5415;4,0705;4,797;4,776;5,309;4,449;3,7735;4,682;5,452;4,181;2,1005;3,5605;7,29;4,395;1,7835;3,9355;7,057;3,9615;2,4725;6,851;8,6805;4,0275;4,838;12,67;8,809;4,287;2,7;5,648;11,209;4,736;2,673;7,982
```

The first column that you get when loading the above data into a data.frame in R is the ID of the cases and it has no meaning.

Variable C is an ordinal variable that can be treated as continuous or it can assume the following levels: 26-30-> normal, 20-25-> mild, 10-19-> moderate, 0-9-> severe

I would like to find the variables that significantly influence variable "C". If the requirements of linear regression were met I could perhaps do this:

fit <-lm (C ~., data = res_final)

and thus obtain the coefficients with the p values of each one of them, but there is a high multicollinearity between the variables.

I tried the Lasso regression:

```
library(glmnet)
model_lasso <- glmnet(x = x, y = y, alpha = 1)
y=scale(res_final$C)
x=scale(model.matrix(C~., data= res_final)[, -1])
model_final_lasso <- glmnet(x = x, y = y, alpha = 1, lambda = cv_error_lasso$lambda.1se)
coef(model_final_lasso)
```

All variables were discarded, something similar happens when I apply ridge and partial least square.

I would appreciate any suggestions that allow me to find which are the variables that significantly influence C.

Comment: There isn't "high multicollinearity," because that term doesn't even apply: when $p\gg n,$ the observations are mathematically guaranteed to be collinear, period.  If you would like relevant suggestions, then please supply more information to distinguish your question from the general question of how to analyze $p\gg n$ regression models.  For instance, what do these variables mean and how might they be inter-related?  What underlying theory do you have that suggests they might be related to `C`?

Comment: The C values correspond to a scale that measures the severity of a symptom, the variables of 7-50 are the result of examinations performed on these patients, each row is a patient. Variable C is an ordinal variable that can be treated as continuous or it can assume the following levels: 26-30-> normal, 20-25-> mild, 10-19-> moderate, 0-9-> severe

Comment: Partial least squares is one possible multivariate tool for use when p>>n.

Comment: @ user332577 The problem with pls is that when I select the number of components it shows me zero.                                                                                                                                 ```library(pls)
res_final<-as.data.frame(scale(moca_final[,-c(2,5)]))
modeloplsr<-plsr(C~.,data=res_final,ncomp=20,validation="CV")
selectNcomp(modeloplsr,method = "randomization", plot = TRUE)


```

Comment: So, basically this is a fishing exercise attempting to find risk factors associated with the examination outcome? Any kind of automated selection procedure is almost guaranteed to find spurious results. The best way forward is to carefully consider each and every variable in relation to each other and the outcome. Draw a causal diagram and this will inform the variable selection. You might find groups of related variables that can be combined/reduced to simplify the analysis.

Comment: @ whuber, @ user332577,@Robert Long Can I use kendall or spearman to find the variables that best relate to C ?, then with the variables that best relate to C, can I do an ordinal regression?